# How to type number without touch input field?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

In my project, here i am use "numericKeyboardInput" directive for numeric keyboard.Its working well but, i want to type some number that time first i want to touch the input field and then type something there,How to avoid this.
Here my numeric keyboard auto open on page load and check input fields auto focus

```
//JS Code
    //--------------- This is directive------------------------------

    (function (){
        'use strict';

        angular.module('numericKeyboard').directive('numericKeyboardInput', numericKeyboardInput);

        function numericKeyboardInput(numericKeyboardService, $timeout, $browser){
            return{
                restrict: 'A',
                require: '^ngModel',
                scope:{
                    ngBind:"=",
                    getterSetter: "&",
                    abondonCallback: "&"
                },
                link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl){
                    scope.numericService = numericKeyboardService;

                    element.bind('click', function(){
                        var element_to_scroll_to = document.getElementById(element.attr("id"));
                        element_to_scroll_to.scrollIntoView({block: "end", behavior: "smooth"});
                        element.addClass("keyboard-focus");

                        ctrl.$viewValue = "";
                        scope.numericService.open();
                        if(attrs.maxLength) scope.numericService.maxLength(attrs.maxLength);

                        if(angular.isDefined(attrs.getterSetter)){
                            scope.numericService.getterSetter(scope.getterSetter);
                        }
                        else{
                            scope.numericService.getterSetter(null) ;
                        }

                        scope.numericService.setModel(ctrl);

                        $timeout(function(){
                            scope.$digest();
                        });



                        scope.$watch('numericService.isDone()', function(value){
                            if(value){
                                element.removeClass("keyboard-focus");
                                if(ctrl.$modelValue !== ctrl.$$lastCommittedViewValue){
                                    scope.abondonCallback();
                                }
                                scope.ngBind = ctrl.$viewValue;
                                $browser.defer(listener);
                            }
                        }, true);


                        scope.$watch('numericService.getModel()', function(){
                            $browser.defer(listener);
                            // if(attrs.formatter==="time"){
                            //  timeFormatter(ctrl.$viewValue);
                            // }
                            scope.ngBind = ctrl.$viewValue;
                            // element.val(ctrl.$viewValue);
                        }, true);
                    });


                    var listener = function(){
                        var formatted = ctrl.$viewValue;
                        if(attrs.formatter==="time"){
                            if(ctrl.$viewValue && ctrl.$viewValue.length>6){
                                ctrl.$viewValue = ctrl.$viewValue.slice(0,6);
                            }
                            formatted = timeFormatter(ctrl.$viewValue);
                        }
                        // scope.ngBind = ctrl.$viewValue;
                        element.html(formatted);
                    };

                    String.prototype.replaceAt=function(index, character) {
                        return this.substr(0, index) + character + this.substr(index+character.length);
                    };

                    var timeFormatter = function(value){
                        var _time = "00:00:00";
                        var curr_index = 7;
                        for(var i = value.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
                            if(curr_index<0){
                                break;
                            }
                            _time = _time.replaceAt(curr_index, value[i]);
                            curr_index--;
                            if(curr_index===5 || curr_index === 2){
                                curr_index--;
                            }
                        }
                        return _time;
                    };

                }
            };
        }
    })();
    //---------------------------This is a template code---------------------------

    (function(){
    'use strict';
    angular.module('numericKeyboard', []);
    angular.module('numericKeyboard').directive('numericKeyboard', numericKeyboard);

    function numericKeyboard(numericKeyboardService){
        return{
            restrict: 'E',
            require: '',
            scope:{},
            template: template,
            link: function(scope){
                scope.numericService = numericKeyboardService;

                scope.append = function(key){
                    scope.numericService.append(key,scope);
                };

                scope.done = function(){
                    scope.numericService.done();
                };
                scope.clear = function(){
                    scope.numericService.clear();
                };
                scope.close = function(){
                    scope.numericService.done();
                    scope.isOpen = false;
                };
                scope.stopPropagation = function(event){
                    event.stopPropagation();
                };


                scope.$watch('numericService.isOpened()', function(){
                    scope.isOpen = scope.numericService.isOpened();
                }, true);
            }
        };
    }
    var template = '\
    <p id="output-text" numeric-keyboard-input="" ng-model="simple" ng-bind="simple" style="padding: 10px;"></p>\
    <div class="keyboard" ng-show="isOpen" ng-click="close()">\
        <div class="keyboard-content" ng-click="stopPropagation($event)">\
            <table style="width: 300px;">\
                <tr>\
                    <td><button class="keyboard-cell" ng-click="append(\'1\')">1</button>\
                    </td>\
                    <td><button class="keyboard-cell" ng-click="append(\'2\')">2</button>\
                    </td>\
                    <td><button class="keyboard-cell" ng-click="append(\'3\')">3</button>\
                    </td>\
                    <td><button style="width: 61px;" class="keyboard-cell" ng-click="append(\'4\')">4</button>\
                    </td>\
                </tr>\
    \
                <tr>\
                    <td><button class="keyboard-cell" ng-click="append(\'5\')">5</button>\
                    </td>\
                    <td><button class="keyboard-cell" ng-click="append(\'6\')">6</button>\
                    </td>\
                    <td><button class="keyboard-cell" ng-click="append(\'7\')">7</button>\
                    </td>\
                    <td><button class="keyboard-cell" ng-click="append(\'8\')">8</button>\
                    </td>\
                </tr>\
    \
                <tr>\
                    <td><button class="keyboard-cell" ng-click="append(\'9\')">9</button>\
                    </td>\
                    <td><button class="keyboard-cell" ng-click="append(\'0\')">0</button>\
                    </td>\
                    <td><button class="keyboard-cell keyboard-dot" ng-click="append(\'.\')">.</button>\
                    </td>\
                    <td><button class="keyboard-cell keyboard-clear" ng-click="clear()">X</button>\
                    </td>\
                </tr>\
                <tr>\
                    \
                    <td><button class="keyboard-cell keyboard-done" ng-click="append(\'+\')">+</button>\
                    </td>\
                    <td><button class="keyboard-cell keyboard-done" ng-click="append(\'-\')">-</button>\
                    </td>\
                    <td colspan="2"><button style="width: 145px;" class="keyboard-cell keyboard-done" ng-click="done()">Set</button>\
                    </td>\
                </tr>\
            </table>\
        </div>\
    </div>\
    ';
    })();

    //--------------------------- This is numeric keyboard service and functions----

    (function(){
    'use stric';

angular.module('numericKeyboard').factory('numericKeyboardService',numericKeyboardService);

function numericKeyboardService(){
    var model = null;
    var opened = false;
    var maxLength = null;
    var getterSetter = null;
    var doneEditing = false;
    var sample = "";

    var service = {
        setModel: setModel,
        clear: clear,
        setModelValue: setModelValue,
        isDone: isDone,
        done: done,
        append: append,
        getModel: getModel,
        open: open,
        isOpened: isOpened,
        close: close,
        maxLength: setMaxLength,
        getterSetter: setGetterSetter
    };

    return service;

    function setModel(newModel){
        model = newModel;
    }

    function clear(){
        model.$viewValue = "";
        model.$render();
        //$scope.sample = "";
    }

    function setModelValue(){
        doneEditing = true;
        if(model.$viewValue===""){
            model.$rollbackViewValue();
            return;
        }
        if(getterSetter){
            model.$viewValue  = getterSetter({newValue: model.$viewValue});
            model.$commitViewValue();
            return;
            // scope.ngBind = model.$viewValue;
        }
        model.$commitViewValue();

    }
    function isDone(){
        return doneEditing;
    }
    function done(){

        this.setModelValue();
        this.close();
    }

    function append(key,scope){
        if(maxLength){
            if(model.$viewValue.length >= maxLength){
                return;
            }
        }
        if(model != null){
            model.$viewValue += key;
            model.$render();
        }
    }

    function getModel(){
        return model.$viewValue;
    }

    function open(){
        maxLength = null;
        doneEditing = false;
        model = "";
        getterSetter = null;
        opened = true;
    }

    function isOpened(dt){
        return true; // this is used bcoz keyboard open automatic
    }
    function close(){
        opened = false;
    }
    function setMaxLength(max){
        maxLength = max;
    }
    function setGetterSetter(GS){
        getterSetter = GS;
    }
}
})();

    //----------------- This is HTMl Code-----------
    <p id="output-text" numeric-keyboard-input="" ng-model="simple" ng-bind="simple" style="padding: 10px;"></p>
```

Check the following plunkr link
http://plnkr.co/edit/h3ag1KfJHxbFWYFj4DVQ?p=preview

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to achieve

Comment: without touch on input field how to set focus and type any text which is goes to input field